# different color of row based on result in PHP

Tags: php

I have following php code which fetches result from mysql table. I want to change color of row if columnX=error

```
    <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="PASS"; // Mysql password
$db_name="syslog"; // Database name
$tbl_name="logs"; // Table name
// Connect to server and select databse
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// deinf host
$color="$host";
echo '<table width="1600" border="2" align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">';
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
//If $color==1 table row color = #FFC600
if($color=='10.0.0.1'){
        echo "<tr bgcolor='#f2f2f2'><td>".$rows['seq']."</td<td>".$rows['host']."</td><td>".$rows['datetime']."</td<td>".$rows['priority']."</td><td>".$rows['program']."</td<td>".$rows['msg']."</t$
}else if($color=='10.0.0.2'){//updated you condition here
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#cccccc'><td>".$rows['seq']."</td<td>".$rows['host']."</td><td>".$rows['datetime']."</td><td>".$rows['priority']."</td><td>".$rows['program']."</td><td>".$rows['msg']."</t$
}
}
echo '</table>';
mysql_close();
?>
```

what is want is that if $color (or host) is = x.x.x.x then show color1, if $color (or host) = y.y.y.y then show color2.

Comment: You can do IF or SWITCH CASE and store the color in a variable like $color. Then no need to do if($color ==1) just display the color in the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code

You have to assign value to `$color` variable

```
echo '<table width="1600" border="2" align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">';
echo '<tr><th>col1</th><th>col1</th><th>col1</th><th>col1</th><th>col1</th><th>col1</th></tr>';

    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

//$color assign here from result
$color=$rows['host'];

        if($color==1){

        echo "<tr bgcolor='#f2f2f2'><td>".$rows['seq']."</td<td>".$rows['host']."</td><td>".$rows['datetime']."</td<td>".$rows['priority']."</td><td>".$rows['program']."</td<td>".$rows['msg']."</td></tr>";

}else if($colorX=='error'){//updated you condition here    


      echo "<tr bgcolor='#cccccc'><td>".$rows['seq']."</td<td>".$rows['host']."</td><td>".$rows['datetime']."</td><td>".$rows['priority']."</td><td>".$rows['program']."</td><td>".$rows['msg']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: It's not working. let me give an example to clear. 
I want that when mysql return result, and if host=10.0.0.1 then that row should it in red.

Comment: i have update question. can u please check. sorry to taking your time in my beginner queries.

Comment: your assigning to  $color  only once. so total while loop will have same value........that is that reason your not getting required one......

Comment: i have updated the code $color=$rows['host']; ...please check with that

Comment: how can i display the columns name in the table?